# I want to re-install ubuntu, how to tell which partition to replace?

Tags: system-installation

I wanted to re-install because the install didn't work properly the first time, how do I tell which partition is the one automatically created when I last installed it?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change the size of the partition, then the Ubuntu installer will ask you if you want to reinstall Ubuntu.

[image: Erase Ubuntu and reinstall]